# ¿Cómo posicionar el Footer hasta abajo?

Tags: html5, css3

Quiero hacer que el `footer` siempre este hasta abajo de todo, en las demás páginas sale bien, pero cuando creo un archivo `html` nuevo se posiciona así. Ya usé el `position:absolute` y `bottom:0` en el `footer`, pero cuando en las otras páginas hago scroll se queda arriba el `footer`,

```css
   
                .foter {
                    display: grid;
                    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
                    background-color: black;
                    color: white;
                    margin-top: 8rem;
                    text-align: center;
                    bottom: 0;
                }
```

```html
<footer class="foter centrar-texto">

        <div class="fb  paddingtop">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/raspados.isla.50" class="footer-span">
                <i class="fab fa-facebook-square tamaño-iconos"></i> <br> Raspados Isla</a>
        </div>
        <div class="paddingtop">
            <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt tamaño-iconos"></i>
            <p>30 Avenida Nte., Gonzalo Guerrero, 77710 Playa del Carmen, Q.R.</p>
        </div>

        <div class=" paddingtop">

            <i class="fab fa-whatsapp-square tamaño-iconos"></i> <br>
            <span class="footer-span">99-99-99-99-99</span>
        </div>





    </footer>
```

**[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es decir: ¿sin importar si hay o no contenido que se mantenga al fondo de tu página? ò ¿qué se mantenga al fondo pero de forma visible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [¿Cómo situar el footer siempre abajo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/60587/c%c3%b3mo-situar-el-footer-siempre-abajo)

Answer (score 2):

Tienes q darle al body un min-height acordé al tamaño que debes dejar para esa imagen o lo que sea que quieras incluir. Además, cómo te responden arriba debes darle un "position". Si el footer está dentro del body pones:

```
  body{min-height:100vh}
```

Esto hará que el alto de tu bodi siempre sea toda la pantalla como mínimo. Si quieres que esté fuera del body el footer puedes hacer un cálculo:

```
 body{min-height:calc(100% - 'altura del footer')}
```

Comment: Cuidado con el nombre que es body, ya que en caso contrario no será identificada por el navegador

Comment: Gracias, el auto corrector del teléfono, no me di cuenta, gracias 

Answer (score 1):

Te falta agregar `position: fixed`.  Cuando usas `fixed` el elemento es posicionado relativo a la ventana del navegador.  Algo asi:

```css
.foter {
                    position: fixed;
                    display: grid;
                    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
                    background-color: black;
                    color: white;
                    margin-top: 8rem;
                    text-align: center;
                    bottom: 0;
                }
```

```html
a
a
a
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
a
a

a
a
a

a
a

a
a

a
a
a

a
a
a

a
a
a

a
a

a
a

a
a

<footer class="foter centrar-texto">

        <div class="fb  paddingtop">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/raspados.isla.50" class="footer-span">
                <i class="fab fa-facebook-square tamaño-iconos"></i> <br> Raspados Isla</a>
        </div>
        <div class="paddingtop">
            <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt tamaño-iconos"></i>
            <p>30 Avenida Nte., Gonzalo Guerrero, 77710 Playa del Carmen, Q.R.</p>
        </div>

        <div class=" paddingtop">

            <i class="fab fa-whatsapp-square tamaño-iconos"></i> <br>
            <span class="footer-span">99-99-99-99-99</span>
        </div>





    </footer>
```

Comment: Ya lo hice, pero de igual manera lo resuelve el problema, cuando tengo una pagina con mucho contenido y tengo que hacer scroll, el fototer se queda en la posicion del bottom:0; pero se queda ahi, cuando haces scroll se ve el footer a la mitad de la pagina, no puedo agregar la imagen, ¿Si me entiendes?

Comment: Perdon, es `position: fixed`

Comment: Una explicación de por que el uso de fixed ayudaría a que tanto el OP como el resto de la comunidad comprendamos tu solución

Comment: position:fixed hará que se quede fijo en una posición de la pantalla, no de tu site, y si no he entendido mal, no eso lo que se pretende.

Comment: @alanfcm en serio usar tantos `<br>`? Porqué no usar un `div` con un `height` alto? `<div style="height: 2000px">Contenido</div>`